# Json Exception and error code -1 while testing Huawei Ads

Tags: ads, huawei-mobile-services

I integrated Huawei Ad for monetization purpose. While testing the application i am getting below error
**call reqNativeAd Code: -1 Msg JSON Exception: Input json string cannot be empty.**

Answer (score 0):

The possible causes for the above error are:

1. Using native ad slot ID in place of Banner AD

   - Use appropriate AD slots. For example, use banner AD slot ID for banner AD
2. Using live slot ID while developing the app

   - Use test slot ID - testw6vs28auh3 for banner ADs while developing the app
3. Using HUAWEI Ads Lite SDK on devices where HMS Core app is not available

   - Please check whether HMS Core is available on your device. Otherwise, please use HUAWEI Ads SDK (com.huawei.hms:ads). Please refer this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-version-change-history-0000001050066909#section5452175218817) for details on different AD SDKs and their compatibility.

[image]

Please check above points and implement the suggested solutions and try again.

Hope you can resolve your issue.